# Catching an exception thrown from a callback in cudaLaunchHostFunc

Tags: c++, exception, cuda, cuda-graphs

I want to check for an error flag living in managed memory that might have been written by a kernel running on a certain stream. Depending on the error flag I need to throw an exception.
I would simply sync this stream and check the flag from the host, but I need to do so from inside a CUDA graph. AFAIK I need to somehow encode this host-side error checking inside a cudaLaunchHostFunc callback.

I am trying to understand how the cudaLaunchHostFunc function deals with exceptions. The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g05841eaa5f90f27124241baafb3e856f) does not mention anything about it.
**Is there any way to catch of an exception thrown from inside the function provided to cudaLaunchHostFunc?**

Consider the following MWE:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

__global__ void kern(){
  int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  printf("Kernel\n");
  return;
}

void foo(void* data){
  std::cerr<<"Callback"<<std::endl;
  throw std::runtime_error("Error in callback");
}

void launch(){
  cudaStream_t st = 0;
  kern<<<1,1,0,st>>>();
  cudaHostFn_t fn = foo;
  cudaLaunchHostFunc(st, fn, nullptr);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

int main(){
  try{
    launch();
  }
  catch(...){
    std::cerr<<"Catched exception"<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Kernel
Callback
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Error in callback
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The exception is thrown but it appears that it is not propagated to the launch function. I would have expected the above launch() function to be equivalent (exception-wise) to the following:

```cpp
void launch(){
  cudaStream_t st = 0;
  kern<<<1,1,0,st>>>();
  cudaStreamSynchronize(st);
  foo(nullptr);
  // cudaHostFn_t fn = foo;
  // cudaLaunchHostFunc(st, fn, nullptr);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

which does outputs the expected:

```
Kernel
Callback
Catched exception
```

Additionally, in the first case, all cuda calls return cudaSuccess.

Comment: How about storing the exception in `data` and checking it afterwards in `launch`?

Comment: I suggest to implement checks inside the `launch` routine following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419700/way-to-verify-kernel-was-executed-in-cuda , then throw the exception explicitly! In addition, you could turn the routine `launch` from `void` to `bool` and if an error occur, return an analogous message to the main. In this way you may avoid the `try-catch` statement as well!

Comment: @AbatorAbetor , Comunicating via data is a good idea. But AFAIK foo is launched asynchronously, so that approach would require to synchronize. Besides, I wanted to do the error checking inside foo because otherwise the host logic cannot be captured into a graph. Maybe I am trying to have the cake and eat it -.-

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou I want to make the logic launch part of a larger CUDA graph, which prevents me from doing the check in the launch function. I also wanted to avoid an explicit synchronization.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that something like cudaLaunchHostFunc waiting to launch the exception until explicit sync happend, cudaDeviceSynchronize. The docs do not mention this explicitly, but I believe cudaLaunchHostFunc launches the function in a new thread. Since one does not have access to this thread control of the exception is lost.
I guess the answer to my question is simply: No :(

Comment: Yes, the host function that is run as a result of `cudaLaunchHostFunc()` is run in a CPU thread that is launched/maintained by the CUDA runtime.  This should be fairly evident since it runs asynchronous to the user's thread that executed the `cudaLaunchHostFunc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I understand now that my question is essentially the same as, for instance, this one: [How can I propagate exceptions between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233127/how-can-i-propagate-exceptions-between-threads)

The techniques used to take exceptions from a worker thread to the main thread also apply here.

For completion, the foo and launch functions in my dummy example could be rewritten as follows

```
void foo(void* data){
  auto e = static_cast<std::exception_ptr*>(data);
  std::cerr<<"Callback"<<std::endl;
  try{
    throw std::runtime_error("Error in callback");
  }
  catch(...){
    *e = std::current_exception();
  }
}

void launch(){
  cudaStream_t st = 0;
  dataD = 0;
  kern<<<1,1,0,st>>>();
  cudaStreamSynchronize(st);
  cudaHostFn_t fn = foo;
  std::exception_ptr e;
  cudaLaunchHostFunc(st, fn, (void*)&e);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  if(e) std::rethrow_exception(e);
}
```

Which prints the expected:

```
Kernel
Callback
Catched exception
```